# hibernate envers mapkeyenumerated

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I m using hibernate envers with auditstrategy and mapping class that contain @MapKeyEnumerated

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@JoinColumn(name = "cp_watching_point_id")
private final Map<TemporalContext, LineCriterionGroups> temporalContexts = new HashMap<>();
```

with hibernate 5.4.3 hibernate envers generate this :

```
select ee__ from WatchingPoint_LineCriterionGroups_AUD ee__ where ee__.originalId.mapkey =  :_p0  and ee__.originalId.WatchingPoint_id =  :_p1  and ee__.originalId.temporalContexts_id = :_p2 and ee__.REVEND is null
```

and all work fine. But if i update hibernate version to 5.4.6 or the last one 5.4.22, envers generate this:

```
select ee__ from WatchingPoint_LineCriterionGroups_AUD ee__ where ee__.originalId.temporalContexts_KEY = :_p0 and ee__.originalId.WatchingPoint_id = :_p1 and ee__.originalId.temporalContexts_id = :_p2 and ee__.REVEND is null
```

and generate an error like :

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: originalId.temporalContexts_KEY of: WatchingPoint_LineCriterionGroups_AUD ...
```

as you can see, the field `originalId.mapkey` become  `originalId.temporalContexts_KEY`

I don't know why and i m stuck because i can't update my hibernate version.

did someone experience the same problem and find a solution?

thanks

Comment: It may be related to the [HHH-14224](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14224)

Comment: @SternK no exactly the same error but perhaps its related, thanks